# How do multi-attribute edge-weights influence community detection?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, networks, partitioning, igraph

My graph consists of a computer network topology where each vertex is a physical node/device (depicted using its IP address). Two vertices will have an edge if the nodes have had communication with each other. We call each communication a *conversation*, which will have multiple packets transferred in both directions. Multiple edges between two nodes are thus obvious.

For any *conversation*, I need to capture multiple features, such as:

1. Bytes transferred between the two nodes
2. No. of packets transferred between the nodes
3. The duration of data transfer between the nodes
4. The inter-arrival time of packets between the nodes

While trying to find communities in my graph, I am coming across certain difficulties:

1. Should I go for multi-attribute edges (with each of the above feature taken as a weight), or should I be taking something like weighted average of all features and make them a single attribute?
2. Will I obtain better results if each of the above feature is taken as a separate edge-attribute? If so, how and why?. Does it influence 'modularity' calculations? Again, how? (Links to past works or papers will do)
3. What algorithms may suit my task well? I do not know about other algorithms apart from Louvain (igraph implementation).

Answer (score 2):

First off, community detection is a also known as graph clustering. They are the exact same thing. Second, I am not aware of any widely used program that works on multi-graphs. The current state of affairs is that you should incorporate your domain-specific knowledge to combine information into a single edge weight and cluster thusly. It is possible of course to create more than one graph and cluster them independently. It could be interesting to analyse/reconcile such groups; it depends on the questions that you are asking. Well  known graph clustering algorithms are indeed Louvain, also RNSC, MCL, APC.